# how to prevent to calling another function in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
function datePicker(event)
{
//do something`enter code here`
}

document.onclick=function() {
//do something
}
```

When I call datePicker() function I want to prevent the calling second method .
How to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event bubbling up to the `document` click listener:

```
function datePicker(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

You can also use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to stop sibling elements receiving the event too, if necessary: [jquery: stopPropagation vs stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/jquery-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation)

jQuery Example with IE8 catered for: http://jsfiddle.net/kHT2A/2/

Comment: Is the function `datePicker` actually receiving an event, or just a parameter called event?

Comment: `stopPropogation` isn't available in IE8 and lower, and `stopImmediatePropagation` isn't available natively in any browser.

Comment: Just found out it's prop/a/gation, not prop/o/gation - you learn something new every day :) Updated answer with the correct spelling Also, see http://jsfiddle.net/kHT2A/1/ for a working example with jQuery