# why does preventDefault not work but return false does

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

Does anyone have any idea why my preventDefault code isn't working? return false returns fine, but it is my understanding that's not really the 'proper' way?

```
 if ($('.signup').length == 0) {
        $('.star').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var starElement = $(this);
            var resourceId = starElement.parents('li').data('id');

            updateFavoritesSpan( starElement, starElement.hasClass('starred') );

            starElement.toggleClass('starred');
            starElement.parents('li').toggleClass('fvtd');
        });
        // voting
        $('.voting').on('click .up', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            sendVote($(this), 1);
        });

        $('.voting').on('click', '.down', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            sendVote($(this), -1);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "isn't working"? What sort of elements are those? And what does this have to do with ajax?

Comment: With all browsers or just certain ones?

Comment: They're anchor links. when you click them it follows the link. these are ajax requests so they shouldnt follow the link

Comment: possible duplicate of [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return false;` does both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`.

`preventDefault` stops the "default" action on the element, `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up to the parent elements.

My guess is that there is an event on the parent that is still getting triggered when you only do `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 3):

**The `return false` is not same as `preventDefault()`.**

In fact `return false` is combination of or is *shorthand* of:

- `preventDefault()`
- `stopPropagation()`

So try adding this as well (along with `e.preventDefault()`):

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a typo, change this:

```
$('.voting').on('click .up', function(e){
```

to:

```
$('.voting').on('click', '.up', function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness:

```
return false
```

also triggers

```
stopImmediatePropagation()
```

which cancels all the subsequent handlers on the same element (might come in handy when working with touchend event and meaning to cancel the subsequent click)
Read here the difference between *stopPropagation()* and *event.stopImmediatePropagation()*: 
[jquery: stopPropagation vs stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/jquery-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation)