# How to prevent jquery mobile toolbar toggle when opening a panel

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a fixed header on my jQuery mobile project that is set to data-tap-toggle="true".

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" data-id="hdr" data-visible-on-page-show="false" data-tap-toggle="true">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
```

The header correctly toggles when tapping on the screen. The problem is that when I tap on a link to open a panel, the header also displays.

```
<a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="bars" id="panel_link">Test</a>
```

Here's my panel:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="right" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b">
    <div class="ui-panel-inner">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

I've tried to blacklist the panel button like so:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#demo-page", function() {
        $("[data-role=header],[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggleBlacklist: "a, button, input, select, textarea" });
});
```

I've also tried to create my own click event that changes the header tapToggle option to false as well as opening only the panel.

```
$('#panel_link').on('click', function (event) {
    $("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar( "option", "tapToggle", false );
alert('test');
    $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open" );
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This could help http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/WXq39/

Comment: @Omar, that approach works. I'm willing to go with it unless there's a  better solution.

Comment: I'm still looking for a better solution. I'm not 100% convinced about it.

Comment: I couldn't come up with another solution. I wanted the header to slide in/out smoothly before opening the panel. I'll keep trying.

Comment: have you got this fixed?

Comment: I've not come up with anything better.

Comment: I couldn't come with something better than the demo I've given before.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $('#panel_link').on('click', function (event) {
        $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open" );
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

See the difference between `stopPropagation` and `stopImmediatePropagation` [jquery: stopPropagation vs stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/jquery-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation)

Comment: That approach causes both the toolbar and panel to briefly flash and then disappear.

Comment: @wmfox3 can you post a jsfiddle for the problem? it will be easy to find the solution then

Comment: @wmfox3 This is likely to happen because you are essentially tapping the screen, so both event will be consumed. I will search for some solution though

Comment: I've not created a jsfiddle before, but here's a shot at it. http://jsfiddle.net/5MXT3/1/