# Preventing Google Maps from stealing keyboard input

Tags: google-maps

On this text field, you can type 'k' and 'm' into the contenteditable field and they correctly appear.

http://jsfiddle.net/MNsBK/

```
keyboardShortcuts: false // Doesn't work
```

But, if you drag the background, you'll lose the ability to type an 'm' or a 'k'.  How do I stop Google Maps from grabbing these keyboard keys ('k' and 'm') ?

Comment: Mate, any luck with the solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be a Div that is editable? I added an input into the div and it doesn't override k & m

http://jsfiddle.net/MNsBK/27/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="keyIn" contenteditable="true">
    <input type='text' />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#map').mouseup(function(){
  $('#keyIn input').focus();
});
```

Let me know if it absolutely has to be an editable div and I'll have a closer look.

Comment: Very close! It does need to be a contentEditable. (The text box I'm using needs to grow based on user input.) I've removed the map feature from my app for now and don't need a solution. Still, an interesting issue.

Comment: @arby perhaps you could use a Textarea instead, along with this plugin http://bgrins.github.io/ExpandingTextareas/

Answer (score 2):

JQuery approach:

```
  $("div [contenteditable=true]").keypress(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
```

[stopPropagation vs. stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation)

After finding that solution, there's an even **easier solution**.

Use `keyboardShortcuts: false` attribute when creating the map instance.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  keyboardShortcuts: false,
  center: {lat: 37.7932339, lng: -122.4077706},
  zoom: 15});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjYT2/2/

---

You can't prevent loosing the focus of the editable div, otherwise the panorama can't work, but you can store the caret position and restore it later (a simple `focus` would make the caret to go to the beginning instead of the original position).

Unfortunately, in a contentEditable enabled div, the method to obtain the current selection is much more complicated than just read/set the `selectStart` value (used by textareas). The best way is to use an external library for that: https://code.google.com/p/rangy/

```
var $keyIn = $('#keyIn');
var savedSel;

$keyIn.bind('keydown mouseup', function(){
    savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
})

$('#map').bind('mouseup', function(){
    rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel);
    savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
    $keyIn.focus();
});
```

The problem with the "k" and "m" keys still happens but only in Chrome