# Rendering a recursive structure using CompositeView while encapsulating each Model in an ItemView with Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, recursion, marionette

I'll start with a clear question and explain on after :
**How to properly encapsulate a model, contained in a `CompositeView`, into an `ItemView`**

My problem is simple, but I can't manage to get something good working.
I have a tree of Notes.
Each note is a Backbone.model and has a `@descendants` collection,
I then have a Backbone.Collection to represent that tree (of which @descendants is an instance)
I setup a basic `CollectionView`, with, as an `itemView`, the `CompositeView`. Everything rendered perfectly and I was quite happy about it. This working solution is shown in the first snippet of code!

Here comes the problem. Building on this, I kinda ran into this issue : [Events fired for whole hierarchy](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/)
which make sense for how my events where bound. At first, I simply added unique selectors (added data-guid to my html elements so I could get them by it) and it worked alright, although it was already getting "hacky". But other similar problem have risen so I decided I needed a solution for this.
So, I told myslef, let's encapsulate each model in an ItemView and use the Composite view to recursively render them.
But... This has not been for the best in all worlds...

Here is what I had in the beginning :

```
class Note.ModelView extends Marionette.CompositeView
  template: "note/noteModel"
  id: "note-item"
  itemViewContainer: ".note-descendants"
  ui:
    noteContent: ".noteContent"
  events:
    "keypress .noteContent": "createNote"
    "click .destroy": "deleteNote"
  # ...
  initialize: ->
    @collection = @model.descendants
  # ...

class Note.CollectionView extends Marionette.CollectionView
  id: "note-list"
  itemView: Note.ModelView
  initialize: ->
    @listenTo @collection, "sort", @render
```

Now I transferred every thing that belongs to rendering the Model in a new ItemView

```
  class Note.ModelView extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "note/noteModel"

    ui:
      noteContent: ".noteContent"
    events: ->
      guid = @model.get 'guid'
      events = {}
      events["keypress #noteContent#{guid}"] = "createNote"
      events["blur #noteContent#{guid}"] = "updateNote"
      events["click #destroy#{guid}"] = @triggerEvent 'deleteNote'

    initialize: ->
      @bindKeyboardShortcuts()
      @listenTo @model, "change:created_at", @setCursor

  class Note.TreeView extends Marionette.CompositeView
    template: "note/parentNote"
    itemView: Note.ModelView

    initialize: ->
      @collection = @model.descendants
      @listenTo @collection, "sort", @render
      _.bindAll @, "renderItem"
    renderItem: (model) ->
      if model.get('parent_id') is 'root'
        itemView = new Note.ModelView model: model
        itemView.render()
        @$el.append itemView.el
    onRender: ->
      @collection.each this.renderItem
      @renderItem @model
    appendHtml: (collectionView, itemView) ->
      @model.descendants.each (note) =>
        iv = new Note.ModelView model: note
        iv.render()
        @.$('.note-descendants').append iv.el


  class Note.CollectionView extends Marionette.CollectionView
    id: "note-list"
    itemView: Note.TreeView
    initialize: ->
      @listenTo @collection, "sort", @render
```

and the noteMode template (parentNote is just an empty template right now)

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs untab">UN</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs tab">TAB</button>
<div class="noteContent">{{{indent}}}{{{title}}}</div>
<button class="destroy"></button>
<div class="note-descendants"></div> # That is where I'm putting the children notes
```

So this is almost working. But it's hacky and.. well it still doesn't quite work. I've been reading through all documentations, and I've read those two links [Derick Bailey on nested structure and CompositeView](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/) and [David Sulc on Nested Views](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/) but I still feel I'm missing some important details.

What I'm looking for, as an answer, is any hint or any common way to manage this with Marionette. I'm really looking for something clean since this is going to be one of the angular piece on which the app will be built.
Maybe also I'm searching in the wrong place? Anything will be welcome!! Thank you very much

I wish you all a very nice night.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/AdWjU, details - http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

Comment: Thank you for linking a link that is already in the question!..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to explain to you, in different words, what Derick Bailey already stated in the blog post you referenced.

**Views**

You need two views to make this work.

The first, the "mother view", is the outer most view which contains the recursive structure as its child nodes. This may either be a Marionette.CollectionView or a Marionette.CompositeView.

The second view is your recursive view, meaning it needs to be a Marionette.CompositeView. You make a Marionette.CompositeView recursive, by NOT specifiying an "itemView" property. In lack of an itemView property, a Marionette.CompositeView will use ITSELF to render the models of the collection it was given.

**Collection**

You need a collection that is either a Backbone.Collection of nested Backbone.Collections, or simply a Backbone.Collection which contains a deeply nested hash. In the latter case, you need not forget to convert the simple hashes to Backbone.Collections when handing them to a Marionette.CompositeView (as done below in the RecursiveView's initialize() method).

**Putting it all together**

```
var RecursiveView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: '#someTemplate',
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = this.model.get('children')
    }
});

var MotherView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: RecursiveView,
    collection: new Backbone.Collection([{key: 'value', children: [{}, {}, {}]}])
});
```

**Problem: Event Bubbling**

Naturally, DOM events will now bubble up, so this code

```
var RecursiveView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    events: {
        'click button': someCallback
    }
});
```

will be a catch-all for the events of the view it references as well as all its descendants.

The easiest solution to this problem is the use of the direct descendant css selectr `>`, e.g.

```
var RecursiveView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    events: {
        'click >button': someCallback
    }
});
```

If that isn't enough, one effective solution would be to prevent the automatic event bubbling, e.g.

```
var RecursiveView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    events: {
        'click button': function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            // or event.stopImmediatePropagation() depending on your use case
            // cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5299841/899586 and 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between this code and the first I posted? None... I have this working thank you very much. I'm a seeking for a way to encapsulate the html produced so the innermost view has only access to its html, not to the whole hierarchy html.

Comment: okay, sorry, misread your post, honest mistake.

why don't you add the direct descendant selector `>` in order to only check for DOM events happening to the direct descendants?

If that isn't enough for you, i would rather attack the problem on the event propagation side: stop event bubbling in your recursive view.

Comment: Okay so, first, thank you for taking the time to answer!
So the solutions you propose do work, they are in fact exactly what I have at the moment.  
The problem really is I find this hacky and I wanted to cleanly encapsulate everything in an ItemView.
But playing with the code around, I've come to the conclusion this might not really be possible because you clearly loses recursivity doing so. And then you just find yourself reimplementing it..
Do you have any hint in that direction?
If nothing else comes up, I'll mark your answer, even though it didn't actually help me, you did take the time!

Comment: The problem is, that the event bubbling is NOT happening in the scope of backbone.view/marionette.view, but purely within the DOM itself. There is no event dispatching happening on the side of backbone/marionette, that you could disable. The event bubbling here is purely a 'feature' of the DOM. Therefore, you would have to build a flat hierarchy in the DOM, because events only bubble up to their parents, not their siblings. Then, you would need the appropriate CSS or JS code, to create the optical illusion, that the DOM elements in question were in fact standing in a visual hierarchy... :)

Comment: event.stopPropagation() is therefore 'a hack' to interrupt a standard feature of the DOM. This could be indeed considered hacky, sincy at other places in your code you might expect the event to bubble up. Therefore, the first solution with direct descendant selectors is generally preferable. But I think there are worse crimes than following solution (2).

Comment: Yeah but a view encapsulate it's DOM elements. So you are not selecting on the whole DOM, but only in the `views.el`. That is why I wanted to try this solution. Direct descendants selectors do get the job done, but as shown in the first link I posted in my question, Derick Bailey do resolve this issue with an ItemView encapsulating everything (actually, it's only a backbone view, but it does emulate an ItemView behavior). That's what led me to try and refactor the CompositeView! Also, I have keyboard shortcut which needs a e.stopPropagation(), and I dont know if it can be a long term solution.

Comment: I'm new to Backbone.Marionette, not to Javascript at all. My last project used Angular and it made it easier to refactor code in directives for highly encapsulated and reusable components. I'm kind of trying to get the right feel for Marionette here. I guess I'll have to stick with this for the moment. Thank you @JohnSpartan .

Comment: You don't really need two views for a tree structure. A single recursive Composite View would suffice. The mother view would be just its root instance.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev you do if you need an outer container to wrap the nested views.