# Styled Select Fields with jquery and HTML Listelements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a little problem with my styled Selectfield. I used for this unordered list elemnts (UL / LI) and a H3.

The problem is to close the "Selectfield" by clicking anywhere on the page.
When i bind a click event to the "document", then don't open the SelectField with the current jQuery code.

I have hidden the UL Element by using CSS (display:none).
To open the Select Fields is not the problem. But only without the $(document).bind('click') [...] code.

I hope anyone have a resolution for my.
Thanks.

And here my HTML Code:

```
<div class="select_container">
   <h3 class="reset">Select Items</h3>
   <ul class="select_elements">
      <li>Select Item 01</li>
      <li>Select Item 02</li>
      <li>Select Item 03</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And here the jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var selectFields = {
        init: function(){

            $('.select_container').on('click',function(){
                $(this).find('ul.select_elements').toggle();
                $(this).find('ul.select_elements').toggleClass('active');
            });

            $(document).bind('click',function(){
                if( $('.select_elements').is(':visible')){
                    $('.select_elements.active').hide();
                }
                else if( $('.select_elements').is(':hidden')){
                    console.log('visible false ...');
                }

            });

        }
    };

    $(selectFields.init);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `.stopPropagation` in `$('.select_container').on('click')` function to prevent triggiring `$(document).on('click')`
2. You need to use `toggleClass` in `$(document).on('click')` too

   ```
   $('.select_container').on('click',function(e){
     $(this).find('ul.select_elements').toggle();
     $(this).find('ul.select_elements').toggleClass('active');
     e.stopPropagation();
   });

   $(document).on('click',function(){  
     if( $('.select_elements').is(':visible')){
        $('.active').hide();
        $('.select_elements').toggleClass('active');
     }
     else {
        console.log('visible false ...');
     }
   });
   ```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/82rGG/)

Answer (score 0):

In jquery and javascript an event bubbles up so you have to use e.stopPropagation() on your container click.

check theese pages [linki1](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) or [link2](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) and a possible solution to your problem could be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectFields = {
        init: function(){
           $(document).bind('click',function(e){
              if( !$('ul').hasClass('active')){
                 $('ul').hide()
                 $(this).find('ul.select_elements').toggleClass('active');     
                 }
            }); 

           $('.select_container').on('click',function(e){
                 e.stopPropagation()
                 if( $('ul').hasClass('active')){
                 $('ul').show()
                 }else{ $('ul').hide()   }
                 $(this).find('ul.select_elements').toggleClass('active');
            });

        }
    };

    $(selectFields.init);
})
</script>
```

With stopPropagation prevent the event from bubbling and being caught by the document when you click on the list 
in some cases you can also use stopImmediatePropagation, for understand differences between stopPropagation and  stopImmediatePropagation check this post [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/jquery-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation)
The only drawback to similar code and to and Batu Zet code, is that If you want the items in the list can be clicked without disappearing, you have to add another stopPropagation on ul tag 
Tis is the final [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/aF2uS/)