# How to stop ng-click from a custom directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/movoheve/1/edit)

Consider the following `myButton` directive:

```
angular.module("Demo", []).directive("myButton", function() {
  return {
    restrict : "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      disabled: "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div class='my-button' ng-class='{ \"my-button-disabled\": disabled }' ng-transclude></div>",
  };
});
```

which can be used like this:

```
<my-button disabled="buttonIsDisabled" 
           ng-click="showSomething = !showSomething">
  Toggle Something
</my-button>
```

How could I stop `ng-click` from executing when `buttonIsDisabled` is `true`?

[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/movoheve/1/edit)

Comment: If you don't use the built in `ng-disabled`, you would probably not want to use the built-in `ng-click` either.

Comment: Actually, neither `disabled` nor `ngDisabled` (which is backed by `disabled`) will have any effect here, since they are placed on a `div` (not an `input` or a `button`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the actual button for your button. You could change your directive to:

```
angular.module("Demo", []).directive("myButton", function() {
  return {
    restrict : "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      disabled: "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: "<button class='my-button' ng-class='{ \"my-button-disabled\": disabled }' ng-disabled='disabled' type='button' ng-transclude></button>"
  };
});
```

Then style it to look like your div. See the [Short Example](http://jsbin.com/movoheve/20/edit) I've made.

Answer (score 5):

You could use capture (**[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)**'s optional third parameter) and stop the propagation of the event (using **[`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)**).

"Capture" allows you to catch the event before it reaches the "bubble" phase (when the triggering of "normal" event-listeners happens) and "stopPropagation" will...stop the propagation of the event (so it never reaches the bubbling phase).

```
element[0].addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (scope.disabled) {
        console.log('Stopped ng-click here');
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsbin.com/gamuxulo/1/edit)**.

Comment: Thanks! One question: Is `event.preventDefault();` really required here?

Comment: You got me :) It seems to work just as good without it, but 1.) it doesn't hurt and 2.) I felt it makes the code more declarative (i.e. it makes it easier to understand that the purpose of that block it to cancel the event).

Comment: capturing phase is not supported on IE, so it will not be cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var clickHandlers = $._data(element[0]).events.click;

      clickHandlers.reverse(); //reverse the click event handlers list

      element.on('click', function(event) {
        if (scope.disabled) {
          event.stopImmediatePropagation(); //use stopImmediatePropagation() instead of stopPropagation()
        }
      });

      clickHandlers.reverse(); //reverse the list again to make our function at the head of the list
}
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IQu4RyRzMolnoJBnFIAu?p=preview)

This solution uses jQuery to deal with cross browser problems. The idea here is to attach our event handler **at the head** of the click handlers list and use **stopImmediatePropagation()** to stop current handlers of the same event and bubbling event.

Also take a look at this: [jquery: stopPropagation vs stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/jquery-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation)

Answer (score 0):

```
<my-button disabled="buttonIsDisabled" 
       ng-click="showSomething = buttonIsDisabled ? showSomething : !showSomething">
```

or

```
<my-button disabled="buttonIsDisabled" 
       ng-click="showSomething = buttonIsDisabled ? function(){} : !showSomething">
```

Is this too simple?

Comment: as I understand, the question asks about stopping ng-click `in a directive` so that we don't need to care about adding this logic everywhere that is using this directive.