# How can I make my AngularJS link disabled?

Tags: angularjs

My code looks like this:

```
    <a ng-disabled="!access.authenticated"
            data-ng-class="{ 'current': $state.includes('home'), 'disabled': !access.authenticated } "
            href="/home/overview"
            title="Home">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>
    </a>
```

I want to make it so that when access.authenticated is false then the link cannot be clicked. What I thought of was changing the link to a button and then styling it like a link. However this does not work as a button does not cause the page URL to change.

```
    <button ng-disabled="!access.authenticated"
            data-ng-class="{ 'current': $state.includes('home'), 'disabled': !access.authenticated } "
            href="/home/overview"
            title="Home">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>
    </button>
```

Can someone tell me how I can do what I need ?

Comment: I think you could try something like this by writing a custom directive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366134/how-to-stop-ng-click-from-a-custom-directive-in-angularjs/23367853#answer-23367853 and use preventDefault

Comment: Hi Royi - Can you explain what you mean with your comment. Note that I am using ui-router. Not sure if that makes a differnce. Thanks

Comment: he says you should switch fro href to ng-href or data-ng-href

Comment: Why should they use `ngHref` here? There is no binding in their `href` value. `ngHref` will do *nothing* here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple directive which intercepts the click event and prevents the page transition based on a scope variable:

```
module.directive('myLink', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      enabled: '=myLink'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function(event) {
        if(!scope.enabled) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
<a my-link="linkEnabled" data-ng-class="{'disabled': !linkEnabled}" href="/home/overview">
  <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw">Link</i>
</a>
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/frXVC/2/)

Answer (score 5):

css:

```
 .inactive {
   color: #ccc;
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
 }
```

html:

```
<a href="some.html" ng-class="access.authenticated ? '' : 'inactive'">some link</a>
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T54AQ/).

Comment: Even with `pointer-events: none`, the link can still be selected with the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in several ways:

- use `ng-disabled`
- use `ng-show`
- manipulate with URL

`<a ng-disabled="!access.authenticated" href="/home/overview"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i></a>`

or

`<a ng-show="access.authenticated" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i></a>`
`<a ng-show="!access.authenticated" href="/home/overview"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i></a>`

or

`<a href="{{getUrl(access.authenticated)}}"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i></a>` - where getUrl() - method for resolving request url

Comment: `ng-disabled` doesn't actually work, because tacking `@disabled` on an `<a>` tag does nothing.