# ng-disabled for href tag in list item not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

What I need is to disable click on `<a>` tag that is in list item in ui list so it wont show include me `<div>` that i have on clicks(except for last list item). I tried with ng-disabled on list item attribute directly and also only in `<a>` tag to add ng-disabled but i am still able to click. Below is my view.

```
 <div class="tab-pane">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-default tab-sm">
        <li class=""><a data-ng-click="vm.sub = 'one'" data-toggle="tab"><strong>
                    Text 1</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a data-ng-click="vm.sub = 'two'" data-toggle="tab"><strong>
                    Text 2</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a data-ng-click="vm.sub = 'three'" data-toggle="tab"><strong>
                    Text 3</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li id="viewAllItems" class="active pull-right"><a data-ng-click="vm.sub = 'four'" data-toggle="tab"><strong>
                    Text 4</strong></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div data-ng-show="vm.sub == 'one'" data-ng-include="'src/app/....tpl.html'"></div>
    <div data-ng-show="vm.sub == 'two'" data-ng-include="'src/app/....tpl.html'"></div>
    <div data-ng-show="vm.sub == 'three'" data-ng-include="'src/app/....tpl.html'"></div>
    <div data-ng-show="vm.sub == 'four'" data-ng-include="'src/app/....tpl.html'"></div> <!-- ngRepeat inside of this template -->
</div>
```

I checked value for vm.enableClick it is false for sure.

Comment: You can't disable a link directly.  You can use a directive to intercept its behavior, and stylize it with CSS to make it "look" disabled.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453833/how-can-i-make-my-angularjs-link-disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use ng-disable on a `<a>` tag, instead you can use a class and the css property pointer-events:none so the click will go through the link.