# How to prevent an a element's click event what bind by angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an a element like this

```
<a class='btn' ng-click="alert('clicked')"></a>
```

in js

```
$scope.alert=(item)=>{alert(item)};
```

I had tested use ng-disabled but dose not work.
this is my html
[image: this is my html]
this is my directive
[image: this is my directive]

**I have many a element in my project  so I want to write a directive like ng-disable how to write it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the way to solve the problem,thank you for all of you to help me solve the problem~

```
    .directive('a', function() {
        return {
         restrict: "E",
         replace: true,
         scope: {

        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            if (attr['ngDisabled']) {
                elem.unbind('click');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the $event object to the function, and you can do it like this,

```
<a class='btn' ng-click="alert($event,clicked)"></a>
```

and in Controller

```
$scope.alert = function ($event,clicked) {
  if (you want to stop) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
  } 
};
```

Comment: I have many a element like this , so i want to resolve this like use ng-disable ,do you have any good suggestion? thanks..

Comment: You do not need a directive for that you can just do  $event.stopPropagation();

Comment: <a class='btn'  ng-click="alert($event,clicked); $event.stopPropagation();"></a>

Comment: if you still want look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366134/how-to-stop-ng-click-from-a-custom-directive-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.alert=(item)=>{alert(item)}
  
  $scope.click = false
  $scope.click_two = true
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <a style=" color: red" ng-click="!click||alert('Test')">Click on this and this will not alert</a>   <br> <br> 
   <a style=" color: blue" ng-click="!click_two||alert('Test')">Click on this and this  Will alert</a>    
</div>
  </body>
```

**when the value of click is true then the function will be called else will not get called**

**Please click on both anchor tags to find the difference**

in your controller,

```
$scope.click = false;
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11088/)

Comment: the downvoter, please run the snippet and check the fiddle, the are working fine

Comment: @Potato Running, please run my snippet. do you find anything wrong in it?

Comment: @Potato Running, is there anything wrong in my snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use interpolation in the `ng-disabled` directive.

```
<!--ERRONEOUS -->
<button ng-click="clicks=clicks+1" ng-disabled="{{checked}}">Button</button>

<!--CORRECT -->
<button ng-click="clicks=clicks+1" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
```

Using interpolation (double curly brackets) converts the boolean to a string. The string "false" is truthy. This is a quirk of JavaScript. **Don't use interpolation in the `ng-disabled` directive**.

THE [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/GfXDq82Lg2R1wdzNsUjF?p=preview)

Comment: I want to use in a element not button , button is no problem now.