# Only target child element even if event handler targets parent as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<section id="first">
    <h1>Colors</h1>
    <section id="red">
        <h1>Red</h1>
        <section id="apples">
            <h1>Apples</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="apples">
            <h1>Strawberries</h1>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section id="orange">
        <h1>Orange</h1>
    </section>
</section>

$('section').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color','yellow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J9kAV/

I want the `section`s to turn yellow when they are clicked. However, as `$('section')` could also refer to their parent elements, it's applying the CSS to them as well.

**How can I tell jQuery to apply the CSS to the clicked child element only and not the parent?**

I don't want to use `$('section section')` because I would also like the parent elements to turn yellow if they are clicked specifically. So I need a JavaScript/jQuery solution, not a selector or HTML solution.

Comment: use h1 instead of section

Comment: looks like your problem is because of the so-called ***event bubbling***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Example: **http://jsfiddle.net/8KLEK/**

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` also works.

Comment: @user3650808 - KingKing is right, better use `e.stopPropagation`, otherwise any other handlers on the clicked element itself might also be prevented ([see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/jquery-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('section').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).css('color','yellow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to change 'this' to 'e.target';

```
$('section').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).css('color','yellow'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J9kAV/5/

A little more info on why this works. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target