# event stopPropagation issue

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

**Fixed -** I had to add a z-index to the form.

When I click on the user-mobile-search it shouldn't close as I have added e.stopPropagation, however it continues to close it. I don't understand why.

html:

```
<form class="user-mobile-search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search Meeu">
    <i class="user-mobile-search-icon icon-search"></i>
</form>
```

js:

```
        mobileSearchBtn.on('click', function(e) {

            e.stopPropagation();

            userNav.toggleClass('open');
            mobileSearchForm.toggleClass('open');
            mobileSearchBtn.toggleClass('active');
        });

        $('body').on('click',function() {

            userNav.removeClass('open');
            mobileSearchForm.removeClass('open');
            mobileSearchBtn.removeClass('active');
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: stopPropagation vs stopImmediatePropagation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/jquery-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, my problem is that it simply isn't working.