# How do I stop a event propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand I need to use the stopPropigation, but how do I get a reference to the event from an onClick function. And Also how do I find out how an event was attached to the element.  So I have a simple button like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="addRoleToReportClicked()">
```

the function looks like this:

```
function addRoleToReportClicked() {
    $('#addRoleDiv').show();
}
```

So Simple.  And was working fine.  Unitl I just did an update of code from work.  Now it does show the div,  but then proceeds to do other stuff, namely re-load the whole page.

I am using firefox and I see that the button now has a "bubbling" and "DOM0" event handlers. I would love to know how that got there, but more importantly 2 questions:

1. How do I stop this in the addRoleToReportClicked() function?  (I assume that I can stopPropogation, but how do I get a handle to the event?
2. Is there any *easy* way to find what code is adding these event listeners? I tried the debug, but that did not show me anything.  I don't want to go through 20+ js files and thousands of lines of code to find it.  But I do want to hunt down the developer and shoot him.

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
    $("#addRoleDivButton").unbind("click").on("click", function(e){
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.bubbles = false;
      $('#addRoleDiv').show();
    });
```

None of it worked.  Taking the idea of a form submition,  I noticed that all the other buttons on the page were working fine, but this one was *inside* a from. So I changed the tag from a "button" to an "a"  and it works fine.  Someone attached a submit() to every button inside a form tag.  How do I stop a submit?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute

Comment: I bet this has nothing to do with event propagation and that you are just submitting a regular HTML form.

Comment: use unbind function in jquery here selection is your element `$( "selection" ).unbind( "click", addRoleToReportClicked() );`

Comment: Quentin,  You may be right...  when I click on the button,  FF gives me a message saying I have submitted a form in some format....  whatever.  How is calling a function that only shows a div,  how is that submitting a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you can stop bubbling, the most popular two ways are -

stop the propagation -

```
function addRoleToReportClicked(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#addRoleDiv').show();
}
```

or, unbind the other handlers -

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-1">

$(".btn-1").unbind("click").on("click", function(){
    $('#addRoleDiv').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) the event is passed as argument to the callback function

```
function addRoleToReportClicked(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#addRoleDiv').show();
}
```

`stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from trigger callbacks on parent elements.

You may want to use `stopImmediatePropagation()` in some cases: I leave to you to look for the difference

[jquery: stopPropagation vs stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/jquery-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation)

Note that you may also/instead want to prevent the browser to execute its default actions: (for example a click on a link would also open the link, a click on a submit button would send the form).

In that case you have `event.preventDefafult()`

**EDIT:**

Note that if `addRoleToReportClicked` is invoked because you have

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="addRoleToReportClicked()">
```

Then the `event` object is not passed to the function

You may remove the `onclick` attribute.

Then if you need to catch the click on the button use Jquery's `on('click')`

---

2) Google Chrome (Dev Tools) tells you what event listeners are attached to an element (just right-click and inspect the element).

AFAIK it doesn't tell you where on the code the event listener were set up.

But if you perform a global search on your sources for the name of the event listener you should find it.

Comment: i think event is not needed as argument you can leave addRoleToReportClicked function empty

Comment: and how do you gain access to the event object then?

Comment: When I do this I get "event is undefined"

Comment: @mmaceachran this is because it's called due to the `onclick` attribute set on the element. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't accepted any of the above answers, I'll add this here.

```
function addRoleToReportClicked(event) {
    $('#addRoleDiv').show();
    return false;
}
```

By adding the `return false;`, it should stop any other functions running. If this or any of the other solutions don't work then there must be something else refreshing the page.

Try and debug it yourself using the `chrome or firefox` debuggers.