# Something blocks addEventListener(type, handler) to work in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I'm learning Vanilla JS and DOM, and I'm testing some codes in console. I have a question.

Step 1) Navigate to website "http://rehub.wpsoul.com" in chrome.

Step 2) Open a console.

Step 3) Write down below code in console.

```
var neww = window.open('/')
neww.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
})
```

This code is not working. However, if I change the event type from 'click' to 'scroll', it does work well.

What makes it hinder to work in DOM?

Whenever I tested this code, some websites does not work event type, 'load' like this website.

I've had a headache for this for a few days. I would like to know the reason and principle of DOM and JS.

I need your help, thanks! :)

Comment: Events can be captured and their propagation can be stopped. You can chek which events are attached to the DOM and how they are handled with the DevTools.

Comment: this is exactly what happens, if you open dev tools in the newly opened window, and delete document level listeners the click will eventually start working

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant Thank you. I've found the eventlistener tab in console according to your comment. https://imgur.com/a/Aing8Lu Could you give me some tips to find what element block my event type? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @maurycy Gotcha! Thank you. You're rIght, it works after I removed all document level listeners. Could you let me know why this blocks my code? I've learned that addEventlistener can add existing addEventlistener handlers  :)

Comment: I don't have Chrome at hands right now, and I can't remember all its tools by heart. But in genereral, events have two phases, capturing phase and bubbling phase, and both of the phases can be prevented to propagate. See [Event Flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).

Comment: There is probably `stopImmediatePropagation()` in one of the event handlers, this is a topic worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299740/stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant Thank you so much!! It helps a lot. You made my day! Have a nice one :D

Comment: @maurycy Thank you so much :) You're right. I found the code "e.stopPropagation();" According to your comment, I can catch the problem! Thank you again :) Have a good one :D

Answer (score 1):

As you are opening a new window and its DOM is not yet available or ready, the event is not getting bind. Please try following code:

```
var neww = window.open('/')
neww.addEventListener('load', function() {
    neww.document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried that and it does not work. If I typed var neww = window.open('/') and after it is fully loaded, then I typed the last code,
function() {
    neww.document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('hi');

It does not work, but event type 'scroll' works. I think it is not related with that.