# Is there a way to stop swipe event propagation from child to parent?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, gsap

I have slides where users can swipe and navigate between different slides but some slides have carousel or nested slides inside slides.so if I swipe carousel, slides navigation occurs which i need to prevent from happening. So i need to prevent Parent element swipe, if child element is swiped. How to achieve the desired behavior? Thanks

using GSAP Draggable , tried giving stopPropagation inside onPress Event

Comment: grab the `event` and `stopPropagation()`

Comment: I am using GSAP Draggable, onPress event I tried doing stopPropagation, still not able to stop child event propagation

Comment: Is it possible the parent events are not related to the onPress but to another/other event(s)? I would suggest adding some debug code to see what is triggering the parent swipes.

Comment: Thanks @Ashley, debugging the same here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) to stop immedeatly, even if there are multiple handlers on the same element.

You can also call [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and check up the chain if it has been called by checking if [Event.defaultPrevented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented) is true

```js
$('button').on('click',(e) => {
  console.log('Strolling along the beach');
});
/**
 * Halt the train modus, only disadvantage, they only halt the train when it's their turn, so the order of event binding is important.
 */
$('button').on('click',(e) => {
  console.log('EMERGENCY BRAKE');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('button').on('click',(e) => {
  console.log('Watch out for seagulls');
});

/**
 * You want everything to continue as normal, and handle aborts "softly"
 */ 
$('div').on('click',(e) => {
  
  if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    console.log("in the coconut");
  }
});
$('a').on('click', (e) => {
  console.log('Seagulls, they poke you');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
a {
   background: red;
   color: #ddd;
   display: inline-block;
   padding:4px;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button>click me!</button>
  <div>
    <a>
    click me
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.Will debug the same and let you know

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend a read of [stopPropagation vs. stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5299841/8319370). It appears `stopPropagation` should work for you if you binded to its child element. See [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

However, if you binded to the same parent, it's important to note `stopImmediatePropagation` won't magically skip previous events.

> Event handlers are executed in the order in which they have been attached to the element.

In this scenario, I would actually recommend debugging from your browser on the events fired to see what is happening.

> - Open `Dev Tools` on Chrome
> - Click the `Sources` tab
> - On right-hand side, scroll down to `Event Listener Breakpoints`, and expand tree
> - Click on the events you want to listen for.
> - Interact with the target element, if they fire you will get a break point in the debugger

Similarly, you can:

> - In the `Elements` tab, select your element.
> - On the right side, there should be a side-tab with `Event Listeners`.
> - Expand the tree to see what events are attached to the element.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this issue is to create an intermediary `element` in between your parent and child, and then on the bubbling phase of a press you could use `event.stopProgagation()`.

That way the child `element` still registers the press/drag/etc

Comment: I will that solution, will let you know soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with GSAP events bcuz dragStart was called after moving 2pixels but event already propagated to parent by that time so I manually added touchstart event and called stopPropagation on it