# Knowing if a default event actually was prevented

Tags: javascript, accessibility, user-experience

I have a modal which I want to close when user pressed the `Escape` key.
However, this modal also contains form fields that may benefit from default behaviours from the browsers.

For exemple an opened `<select>` element will close when hitting the `Escape` key.
If this happens I don't want to close the modal since I consider the user wanted to close the `<select>` when hitting `Escape`. However, when it is already closed, I want the modal to close.

The question is:
**Is there a way to know whether a default event was fired or not?**

It seems the `defaultPrevented` property is called whenever `preventDefault()` was, whether or not it actually prevented something.

Answer (score 0):

Closing modals is no default event, so you have to make use of `event.stopPropagation()`.
You just have to add `event.stopPropagation()` on the selects keydown event, to prevent the Escape button from closing the modal.

You should check out [the difference between event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963688/10304804) and [stopPropagation vs. stopImmediatePropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60862319/10304804).

Comment: I understand that `event.stopPropagation()` would help me. However, how do I call this method only in the case that there actually was a default event triggered.
Say my `<select>` is closed, I don't want to stop the propagation of the event. I do want it to reach the modal so it can be closed.

Comment: You can't check if the default-select-dropdown is open or not. (maybe with some handlers, but it won't be 100% accurate) - You could also just tab in it and press up/down-arrow keys to select something. - You can make use of the bubbling phase and watch the same event on two different nodes (select and it's parent node) and check on both if event.defaultPrevented is false/true. If it's still false on the parent the default-browser-event was executed.